# Convert Int List Into Integer

Tags: c#

This is a bit of an odd case I must admit, but I'm trying to find a succinct and elegant way of converting a `List<int>` into an actual `int`.  For example, if my list contained entries 1, 2, and 3, then the final integer would be 123.  The only other way I thought of doing it was converting the array to a string and then parsing the string.

Any hints?

Comment: Beware that the contents of your list must produce a valid int (that is, an integer in the range -2,147,483,648 through +2,147,483,647).

Comment: Also, what should happen if your list is something like { 100, 1, 0, 2 }?

Comment: What's the rule if your list contains values >= 10? e.g. would 1, 20, 33, 4 become 120334? If so, the "multiples of 10" answers below will fail.

Comment: Also, what about negatives? Why not use an unsigned type instead?

Comment: @Humberto: then the resultant number would be 100,102 would it not?

Comment: How do you use something like this in a normal production application?

Comment: @Evan: when I'm parsing address data such as house numbers containing "13a", I pop the integers onto a list until I encounter a character, then I convert the integer list into the actual int.  Whilst this was a good test for me, I later used regex to deal with the issue.

Comment: @Kezzer Interesting. Never heard of anybody using that approach before.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Iterate the list, as if adding a sum, but multiply the running total by 10 at each stage.

```
int total = 0;
foreach (int entry in list)
{
    total = 10 * total + entry;
}
```

Comment: What if the entries are not single digits?
Lets say:
{1,3,15}
Expected result: 1,315
Actual result: 145

Comment: @RonK. True, it carries the extra digit. The problem was presented with single digits, for which it works, but more clarity is needed here on the desired result I agree.

Comment: Well spotted RonK, in any other case this would be true.  For me it isn't as I'm iterating over a character array so I think this will work.  Will test after lunch.

Answer (score 4):

```
List<int> l = new List<int>();
// add numbers
int result = int.Parse(string.Join(",", l).Replace(",", ""))
```

You'd have to take care if the list is long enough so that the resulting number would exceed the limits for an int though.

Comment: Couldn't you just do `int.Parse(string.Join("", l))` ?

Answer (score 2):

Say, you have an enumerable like

```
var digits = [1, 2, 3 ...];
```

then you could do:

```
// simplest and correct way; essentially the accepted answer but using LINQ
var number = digits.Aggregate((a, b) => a * 10 + b);

// string manipulation; works for sets like [10, 20, 30]
var number = int.Parse(string.Join("", digits));

// using `Select` instead of `Aggregate` but verbose; not very useful
var number = (int)digits.Select((d, i) => d * Math.Pow(10, digits.Count() - i - 1)).Sum();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you suggestion is pretty good, something like this works:

```
var list = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
var listAsString = String.Join("", list.ConvertAll(x => x.ToString()).ToArray());
Console.WriteLine(listAsString);
int result = Int32.Parse(listAsString);
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it by adding all the numbers in a loop. Not sure it's faster than string parsing though:

```
List<int> list = new List<int> {1, 2, 3};
int sum = 0;
int pow = list.Count - 1;
for (int i = 0; i <= pow; i++)
{
    sum += list[i] * (int)Math.Pow(10,(pow-i));
}
```

Also if you have a long list, you might want to use .Net 4's BigInteger class instead of an int.

Answer (score 0):

Well just for fun (I have no idea how effecient this is, probably not very), you can also do this easily with Linq...

first convert the list of ints to a list of strings, then use the aggregate function to concatenate them, then at the end use in32.TryParse to make sure the resulting value is in the int range.

```
string val = ints.Select(i=> i.ToString()).Aggregate((s1, s2) => s1 + s2);
```